# How to make OR in javax constraint validation?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator

I would like to find out some solution for making `or` in javax validation.
Something like:

```
@Null
@Or
@MyCustomValidation
private MyObject myObject;
```

Or something like this. So, basically, I would like to call `MyCustomValidation` only if the field is not null. Otherwise, it should be valid also.
I could of course add additional logic in `MyCustomValidation` to return true if myObject is null, but then I should add this logic in many validators which looks not nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having your validator returning true for null values is indeed what we recommend when developing your custom validators.

Apart from `@NotEmpty` which is a bit special, all the validators provided by Hibernate Validator follow this rule.

It allows you to compose if with the `@NotNull` constraint when you want a non null value.

I don't think this additional logic would be an issue, it's very simple. And if it is, you can still have an abstract parent class.